# How can you buffer two online videos alternately while playing one of them?

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, buffer, buffering

On my website, I want my user to be able to launch video 2 at any point in the middle of video 1 without waiting or refreshing the window. How can I buffer the two videos such that I buffer video 1 enough to let it start playing, and then buffer just enough of video 2 that if the user launches it at any point, he does not have to wait to view its first few seconds, and then I can come back and buffer the rest of video 1? If this is not possible, I could also look at buffering video 1 and 2 in parallel while playing only video 1. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  And it is probably not necessary.  With some buffer configuration tuning, you should be able to switch between videos with negligible buffering of either video.